# Check if a Location is out of a Area radius

Tags: java, android, gps

I have a Area with a Radius of 450 m. is there a way to check if a Location(Latitude,Longitude) is out of this Radius or not?

[image]

Comment: "I tried a lot of solutions but without success"... show your working?

Comment: @AlexWien and how did you know that?

Comment: A simple search woth "coordinate  in circle" reveal many solutions

Comment: You use arithmetic. If that doesn't work, show your work, and let's go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `distanceBetween()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29) to see if the two points are greater than 450m apart, using the center of your area as the starting point.

Comment: Ok ill try it. thank you